# Do you need to migrate SQL server 2008 to Azure SQL?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, azure, azure-sql-database

I am currently learning Azure. In terms of data store, I see Azure SQL and the migration tool. If you have SQL server 2008 or Oracle, would you be required to migrate in order to use Azure?
I know you can access/query the Azure datastore via web browser or azure tools. Is there anything equivalent to working locally (or setting up local azure sql db)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure is a platform with various components. you can opt to migrate your database to Azure SQL Database, run a Azure VM with either Oracle or SQL Server, or retain your current databases on-premise and make use of VPNs to connect your on-premise databases and your Azure-based application.

There is no emulator for Azure SQL Database. for local development, you can point it to as SQL Express, LocalDB or SQL Server.